# Handle java.lang.NullPointerException in Scala

Tags: java, scala

Say I have a model class as shown below:

```
class User () {
  var id: Option[java.lang.Long] = _
  var name: Option[String] = _
  var date: Option[java.util.Date] = _

  def this(id: java.lang.Long,name: String, date: java.util.Date){
    this()
    this.id=Option(id)
    this.name=Option(name)
    this.date=Option(date)
  }
}
```

I tried to create an object by doing

```
var obj = new User
obj.id=12345
obj.name=user
```

Obviously `obj.date` is `null`, and I kept getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at this point. How should I handle this exception?

Comment: Why do you need a zero-arg constructor? If you're going to initialise the fielsds immediately, have a constructor do that (then that can initialise the date field appropriately -i.e. None)

Comment: @JonnyHenly, it's not clear to me that lazy vals are needed or desirable here.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I need to initialize because it just wont write to my neo4j if i dont. I am still grasping the enviroment.

Comment: So `def this(id: java.lang.Long,name: String){this()
    this.id=Option(id)
    this.name=Option(name)
    this.date=None}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to initialize the values directly through the constructor. This looks like a POSO (Plain Old Scala Object), so maybe you would be better off with an immutable case class:

```
case class User(id: Option[Long], name: Option[String], date: Option[Date])
```

Now if you want to initialize only some of the properties, you can either pass `None` or create an auxiliary constructor via the companion object:

```
case class User(id: Option[Long], name: Option[String], date: Option[Date])
object User {
  def apply(id: Option[Long], name: Option[String]) = {
    User(id, name, None)
  }
}
```

### Edit:

If Java interop is important, you can define multiple constructors inside the case class which will be visible in Java:

```
case class User(id: Option[Long], name: Option[String], date: Option[Date]) {
  def this(id: Long, name: String) = {
    this(Some(id), Some(name), None)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that in the first attempt, but then it wont let me write to neo4j using spring-data-neo4j driver, but this way seems to do it.

Comment: *but then it wont let me write to neo4j using spring-data-neo4j driver* What does that mean? What happens when you attempt to write something?

Comment: successful with no error but the model wasnt inserted

Comment: @kenlz Perhaps spring-data-neo4j requires your classes to be complying JavaBeans. To achieve that with scala case classes, either annotate every field with a `@BeanProperty`, or define your own getters in vanilla java format.

Answer (score 1):

One nice thing about `Option[T]` is that it has a safe default value `None`. So initialise your vars to `None` instead of `null`.

You should also think about making your model class immutable.

Comment: I tried that, and I get a java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.None$ cannot be cast to java.util.Date, I think i need to manually initialize a default Date value if null were found

Comment: @kenlz, please update the question with your code because that doesn't sound correct.  You assign None to an Option[Date], not a Date

Answer (score 0):

More easy way to do this is

```
case class User(id: Option[Long]=None, name: Option[String]=None, date: Option[Date]=None)
```

In this case if you give a value it takes the value or else it would take None as a default value.